# Django tests: how to specify the apps whose databases I want to use?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, django-1.8

My default database is not being migrated into Django's test database. A database is being created with default tables that Django uses to log tests (such as `django_content_type` and `django_admin_log`), but not my app's tables.

When I run the tests with a verbosity level of 3 (`-v 3`), I see that my app is categorized under `Synchronizing apps without migrations`... which confirms that the migrations aren't being performed.

I don't, however, know how to tell Django's tests to migrate my app's database tables. I can output `python manage.py makemigrations` easily but apparently that doesn't carry over to the tests.

What am I missing?

Thank you!

**Edit**: Sorry, I meant the relations are not being created. I want to test views which rely on models in the database. In order to do so, I'm uploading fixtures (to not deal with data on production). However, when I try to upload a fixture I get a `relation "mymodel" does not exist` error.

Comment: As vmonteco pointed out, Django stands up a parallel database for testing that gets rebuilt each time.  This database is created using the current state of your models.py files and won't have data unless you load it via fixtures, so migrations are generally irrelevant.  What issue are you having that you care about the migrations?

Comment: Ah, "migrations" may not have been the right term. I meant relations (the schemas)

Comment: Can you provide a minimum example of what your problem is?  This sounds (and @vmonteco's update addresses this with the links to the tutorial) that you're not quite understanding how Django "wants" you to test stuff.  I suggest searching for the term "fixture" in the links on testing to see how you can have your test database table have some initial values for a view to get stuff from

Comment: Please provide a simplified version of your models.py and test.py (and views.py for completeness); that will make troubleshooting why you're getting that error substantially simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's tests are designed to create a test database to perform tests.

I think that making your tests depend of a prod database is a bad idea.
You should design your tests to cover as many cases as possible, not to check if it works with your current database (which can evolve).

Here are some pages about testing with django 1.8 :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial05/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to test a view which gets objects from a table in a database... but since the table doesn't exist, I can't test the view.

Comment: You can design your tests to create a test table. If you look at the example here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial05/#testing-our-new-view you can see that the tests are designed to create some objects to test the code with different cases. Test database will be deleted after the test.

Comment: Thanks vmonteco, but at what point are the tables defined? I've tried to create objects in a similar way but I still get a `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "xxx" does not exist` error.

Comment: They are created for each test, you create the objects before checking the assertion, but perhaps it is something about your models, or a code error. Could you - as Foon suggested- provide some code?